# Does OpenGL guarantee a rasterization order for GL_LINES or GL_LINE_STRIP?

Tags: c++, opengl

If I render a poly line using `GL_LINES` or `GL_LINE_STRIP` can I assume that the line segments with the low vertex indices are drawn to the frame buffer first? Like, when I specify a line strip using the vertices v0,v1,v2 can I assume segment v0v1 is rendered first, then v1v2?

Answer (score 4):

The OpenGL standard is defined on the notion that everything will behave "as if" everything executed in a particular order. As such, it defines a rigid order for pretty much everything.

When it comes to vertices and primitives within a rendering command, yes, there is an order. Specifically, everything is taken in the order you submit the data. Each vertex is taken in turn from first to last within the `glDrawArrays/Elements` call. And as the vertices are converted into primitives, this assembly orders the generated primitives. The primitives are generated in the order in which their incident vertices are encountered.

Or rather, OpenGL behaves "as if" the submission order is followed. The fact is however, the only place where you can *tell* whether any of this is true is in the order their fragments get put into the framebuffer. So implementations can process primitives asynchronously, but then do blending of the individual pixel data from these primitives based on the submission order.

But those are implementation details. The point is that if you render 2 lines in the same draw call, and they overlap, and you have blending turned on, OpenGL *guarantees* that they will be rendered as if the line formed from the first two vertices in the array was fully rendered, then the line formed from the later vertex(ices) was rendered. And thus, they will be blended in that order.

The only rendering operations which are explicitly unordered in OpenGL are [incoherent memory accesses](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access) and the order of primitives generated by [tessellation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation). And the latter only allows them to be unordered within that patch; all primitives from one tessellated patch must be rendered (as if) before any primitives from a later one.

Comment: And when will this order be enforced? I know that vertex and fragment shaders can run in parallel. What will happen if a line at the back of the buffer finishes with its shaders first? Will it wait for the shaders of the lines with the low indices so everything can be blended in the right order?

Comment: @Desperado17: You cannot tell "when" it gets enforced; anything you might try to do in a shader to detect that will necessarily break the [OpenGL memory model and invoke undefined behavior](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access). Just let the GPU do its job.